# how to create multiple radio buttons in single row for minimum 4 questions?

Tags: android

how to create multiple radio buttons in single row  for minimum 4 questions  and answer in form of yes or no at finally it have to calculate how many yes and how many no

like:

1. Are you going to office yes/no
2. Are you going by bus/cab
3. Are you interested to attend seminar yes/no

Finally, the result has to be counted using button

Comment: put the code what you were working on sir

Comment: am new to android i tried but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Are you going to school "/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No"/>
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

This makes your one question.Make other three question like this and store status of radiobutton in one array.And finally ,calculate and show.

Comment: thanks rohit what about java class am having doubt in that also

Comment: help for java class